# VBA Range with string

Tags: excel, vba

I'm relatively new to programming and just ran into a VBA issue when trying to select a range in Excel. Can someone please help me understand why below code doesn't work...

```
Dim rangeHeuristics As range
Dim test As String

test = "Cells(50, 9), Cells(52, 24)"

Set rangeHeuristics = range(test)
rangeHeuristics.Select
```

But below code does...

```
Dim rangeHeuristics As range

Set rangeHeuristics = range(Cells(50, 9), Cells(52, 24))
rangeHeuristics.Select
```

What is the difference between both sets of code?

Thanks.

Kind regards
Jan

Comment: The first contains a string, the second contains members of the Excel object model. In other words, `"Cells"` is not equivalent to `Cells`.

Comment: If you need to use `String`s then do something like: `Range("I50:X52")` or `Range("I50", "X52")`. But if you have the column and row numbers, it is easier to use `Cells` like you have in the second snippet.

Comment: Please note you can also use `Cells(50, "I")` instead of `Cells(50, 9)`.

Comment: @SuperSymmetry I strongly recommend not using that notation because it leads to a false understanding of how the row and column are interpreted by the `Cells` method. Take for example `Range("B3").Cells(4,"B")`. Someone might falsely understand that saying "B" means column "B" when it actually means "the second column from my top left corner. So in this case `Range("B3").Cells(4,"B")` is C6

Comment: @Toddleson Great point. This might be a result of the misunderstanding of the relitivity of `Cells` to its parent and not the use of `"B"` vs `2`. I suspect it is just as easy to misinterpret `Range("B3").Cells(4, 2)`.